# WiFi issues with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, usb, asus

I just bought a Asus N66 USB WiFi adaptor, I've got it installed with drivers that came with the CD. But as soon as I start any programs that requires internet access Ubuntu freezes.

Anyone that can help me?

Comment: Did that came with drivers for linux? Also can you try a differente kernel? What erros do you get?

Comment: Which CD? The one that came with your wifi adapter, or a Ubuntu installation CD?

Comment: The one that came with adapter adapter

Comment: The CD that came with WIFI adapter. I'm not sure which errors I get, because ubuntu just freezes and when I reboot and check system log I can't find anything specific, although I am a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you solve your problem:

http://stuff.purdon.ca/?page_id=8

Comment: I've tried that also, and the original drivers that came. None of them works for me. I can't even use the PCs reboot button or sleep function from keyboard.